# Change background-color of mat-button-focus-overlay without !important

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

Angular Material documentation has something that I would like to reuse, and I would like to do it in correct way:
https://material.angular.io/components/categories
I would like to have buttons on the top bar with the same div.mat-button-focus-overlay which have:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

No matter what I do everything I've got is this:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
   background-color: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.12);
}
```

And this leaves me with the same color as a bar, so the overlay on hover is not visible. Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwmxw7

How to do it in correct way? I wouldn't like to use any hacks, only best practices :)

### EDIT:

I've found something strange... when I put this to scss file of the component:

```
body mat-toolbar.mat-toolbar button.mat-button div.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

It doesn't work, it looks like it doesn't even exist on the list of styles in browser (?), but the same code moved to style.scss works like a charm... Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the same effect as the angular material doc page. Simply remove the color binding from your button. The text-color is also not necessary.

**component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  <button mat-button>test</button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Oh man! You saved my time. Thanks! 
Do you know why the thing described by me in EDIT happens?

Comment: The component styles only apply to the components template.You can't create a css selector starting outside of this component. body is not part of the component and therefore the selector only works in the global styles.css

If you add a class to body you can create a selector within the compnent with: host-context(.body-class) body ...

Comment: Good piece of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work for angular 15 and angular material 15

Answer (score 0):

You can override classes in a way that others can override your changes as well in many ways. Here's just one example that should work.

```
body .mat-button-focus-overlay
```

You can read about more specificity battles here.

https://css-tricks.com/a-specificity-battle/

Answer (score 0):

I used this method

```
::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: red!important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```